Get filenames FSO with rename of file names to get specific name structure using VBScript
I need to rename the following files by removing all the numeric digits that have been associated after the first zero of the file name.
The only part of the file name that I know, the fixed part is this:
StT_QX10
StT_QY20
StT_QE50
StT_QG70
StT_QH90

However, the variable part of the file name that is automatically assigned by the server that generates these text files is unknown for each day, the always different and variable part is this
_46_9448513023277552554
_31_7886000158142287461
_55_2426936282534604666
_39_8749067416635922512
_27_2363684982157969174

Input
StT_QX10_46_9448513023277552554.txt
StT_QY20_31_7886000158142287461.txt
StT_QE50_55_2426936282534604666.txt
StT_QG70_39_8749067416635922512.txt
StT_QH90_27_2363684982157969174.txt

I mean the output I need is as below
Output
StT_QX10.txt
StT_QY20.txt
StT_QE50.txt
StT_QG70.txt
StT_QH90.txt

The numeric digits associated after the first zero digit of the file name are absolutely random and there is no way to know them in advance. But their number is always fixed, that is, first 2 digits preceded and followed by an underscore and then 19 digits without interruption
_46_9448513023277552554.txt
_31_7886000158142287461.txt
_55_2426936282534604666.txt
_39_8749067416635922512.txt
_27_2363684982157969174.txt

I'm stuck here
   Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   
   Arr = Array("StT_QX10", "StT_QY20", "StT_QE50", "StT_QG70", "StT_QH90")
                       
   For I = 0 To UBound(Arr)
      If FSO.FileExists("C:\BOE\StT_" & Arr(I) & "") Then    
   
   Else
      MsgBox("The file does not exist : " & vbcrlf & Now() & vbcrlf & Err.Number & vbcrlf & Err.Description)
   
   End If    
   Next

   Set FSO = Nothing   


Does it have to be scripted?  You could  use BRU.

If all files are like the provided examples, then all that's needed is to trim the last 23 characters from the base file name. If the last part of the file names vary in length, then another simple approach is to split on the underscore character and keep the first two parts. Here are examples of each approach:
Example 1: Trim the last 23 characters
folderPath = "C:\temp"
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = oFSO.GetFolder(folderPath)

For Each file In folder.Files
  If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(file.Name)) = "txt" And Left(file.Name, 4) = "StT_" And Len(file.Name) > 27 Then
    BaseName = oFSO.GetBaseName(file.Name)
    file.Name = Left(BaseName, Len(BaseName) - 23) & ".txt"
  End If
Next

Example 2: Split on underscore and keep the first two parts
folderPath = "C:\temp"
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = oFSO.GetFolder(folderPath)

For Each file In folder.Files
  If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(file.Name)) = "txt" And Left(file.Name, 4) = "StT_" And Len(file.Name) > 27 Then
    BaseName = oFSO.GetBaseName(file.Name)
    a = Split(BaseName,"_")
    file.Name = a(0) & "_" & a(1) & ".txt"
  End If
Next


[REWRITE]
This problem can be made easier with regular expressions to validate the filename and to capture/discard portions of the filename:
dim fso, folder, f, rx, m, newname
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set rx = New RegExp
rx.Pattern = "^(StT_QX10|StT_QY20|StT_QE50|StT_QG70|StT_QH90)_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{19}(\.txt)$"
For each f in fso.getFolder("C:\BOE").Files
   Set m = rx.Execute(f.name)
   If m.Count > 0 Then
     newname = m(0).Submatches(0) + m(0).Submatches(1)
     WScript.Echo "Rename: " + f.name + " to " + newname
   End If
Next


Thanks a lot for reply. But it seems that this does not solve my problem, I don't know the name of the files to rename initially. With your suggestion it is thought that I know the name of the file in advance...

Okay, done. I have edit my first question.  I hope you understand

Rename Files By Base Name
Option Explicit

RenameFilesByBaseName

Sub RenameFilesByBaseName()

    ' Define constants.
    Const FOLDER_PATH = "C:\BOE\"
    Const FILE_EXTENSION = "txt"
    Dim NEW_BASE_NAMES: NEW_BASE_NAMES = Array( _
        "StT_QX10", "StT_QY20", "StT_QE50", "StT_QG70", "StT_QH90")
    
    ' Create an instance of the FileSystemObject object.
    
    Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' Return all files with the specified extension in a dictionary.
    
    Dim dict: Set dict = DictFilesInFolder(FOLDER_PATH, FILE_EXTENSION, fso)
       
    If dict.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No """ & FILE_EXTENSION & """ files found in """ _
            & FOLDER_PATH & """!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
                  
    ' Rename the first found file (assuming only one) 
    ' that begins with the new base name to 'the new base name'.
    
    Dim OldName, i, NewBaseName, NewName, WasFileFound
                       
    For i = 0 To UBound(NEW_BASE_NAMES)
        NewBaseName = NEW_BASE_NAMES(i)
        WasFileFound = False
        For Each OldName In dict.Keys
            If InStr(1, OldName, NewBaseName, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then ' begins w
                WasFileFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If WasFileFound Then
            NewName = NewBaseName & "." & FILE_EXTENSION
            If fso.FileExists(fso.BuildPath(FOLDER_PATH, NewName)) Then
                MsgBox "The file """ & NewName & """ already exists in """ _
                    & FOLDER_PATH & """!", vbExclamation
            Else
                dict(OldName).Name = NewName
                MsgBox "Renamed """ & OldName & """ to """ & NewName & """.", _
                    vbInformation
            End If
            dict.Remove OldName
        Else
            MsgBox "No file beginning with """ & NewBaseName & """ found!", _
                vbExclamation
        End If
    Next
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Files renamed.", vbInformation

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a dictionary holding all files with a specific extension
'               ('FileExtension') in a folder ('FolderPath') using
'               the FileSystemObject object ('fso').
'               The keys will hold the file names
'               while the corresponding items will hold the file object.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function DictFilesInFolder(ByVal FolderPath, ByVal FileExtension, ByVal fso)
    
    Dim dict: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim fsoFile, CurrentFileExtension
    
    For Each fsoFile In fso.GetFolder(FolderPath).Files
        CurrentFileExtension = fso.GetExtensionName(fsoFile)
        If StrComp(CurrentFileExtension, FileExtension, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Set dict(fsoFile.Name) = fsoFile
        End If
    Next
    
    Set DictFilesInFolder = dict

End Function

